# close gaps between back button and icon in android

Tags: java, android

I have added a back button and icon to my android action bar. There appears to be much gaps between the back button and the icon as shown in the image below
[image]

this is the code snipet I am using to arrive at the above

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Please how can I close the gaps between the back button and launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following changes in tool `xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```

Since you aren't using toolbar in xml. You will have to create your own style which will have parent as current theme. I can't tell you how exactly since i don't know which theme you are using. Here is an example

```
<style name="myToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:contentInsetLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

Then i will use `myToolbar` theme in application tag in `manifest`. I hope this will help you.

Comment: please where can I find tool xml

Comment: are you using toolbar in your activity's xml?

Comment: oh use ```app``` instead of ```android``` as namespace in ```myToolbar``` if this doesn't solve your problem then you can use noaction parent theme and use toolbar in your activity's xml and use the code that i provided earlier

Comment: please paste code of styles.xml and your activity's xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148620/discussion-between-parker-and-zeeshan-shabbir).